# Delete text starting with specific letter

Tags: excel, vba, notepad++

So I am a complete noob regarding programming, go easy on me guys.

I am in the need to be able to delete text starting with a specific letter.

For example, let's say I have the following:

```
X10 Y20 Z30
Z10.34 X40.22 Y32.12
Y-90 Z-39 X-20
```

And I need to delete every word starting with letter Z and only this word. Everything else must stay untouched. How would I accomplish this? I currently am looking solutions that can be done on Excel or Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick User Defined Function that should accomplish the removals.

```
Function noZeds(str As String, Optional delchar As String = "Z")
    Dim tmp As Variant, i As Long

    tmp = Split(str, Space(1))

    For i = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
        If UCase(Left(tmp(i), 1)) = UCase(delchar) Then tmp(i) = vbNullString
    Next i

    noZeds = Application.Trim(Join(tmp, Space(1)))
End Function
```

Note that the function defaults to removing 'words' that start with *Z* but you can change that character to anything you want by specifying the optional argument.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `Z\S+\h*`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
Z       # literally, letter Z
\S+     # 1 or more non space characters
\h*     # 0 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Result for given example:**

```
X10 Y20 
X40.22 Y32.12
Y-90 X-20
```